# kendo ui grid filter doesn't work for integer type columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, typescript, kendo-grid

I have a problem with Kendo UI. I can't filter on some columns.

Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OfzaIlyRp299sT3Qe3SS) with my example where I try to filter on the columns id, prog or Max Temps and it doesn't work.

```
<body>
    <div id="grid"></div>
</body>
<script>
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: [
            { id: 36308, reportDate: "2015-02-01", prog: 58, state: "Waiting", maxTemps: 0 }, 
            { id: 36309, reportDate: "2015-02-01", prog: 34, state: "Complete", maxTemps: 86400 },
            { id: 36310, reportDate: "2015-02-01", prog: 116, state: "Complete", maxTemps: 86400  },
            { id: 36311, reportDate: "2015-02-02", prog: 58, state: "Complete", maxTemps: 86400 }
        ],
        filterable: true,
        columnMenu: true,
        columns: [
            { field: 'id', title: 'Id', width: '80px' },
            { field: 'reportDate', title: 'Report Date', width: '100px' },
            { field: 'prog', title: 'Prog', width: '60px' },
            { field: 'state', title: 'Status', width: '130px' },
            { field: 'maxTemps', title: 'Max Temps', width: '100px' }
        ]
    });
</script>
```

I have this error on Chrome:

> Uncaught TypeError: (d.prog || "").toLowerCase is not a function

and this one on Firefox:

> TypeError: "".toLowerCase is not a function.

I think it's because my data type is integer on these columns. I don't know how to solve this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define the type number so that there wont be any issue with number filtering. Refer below code

```
columns: [

    { field: 'prog', type:'number',  title: 'Prog', width: '60px' },

  ]
```

Comment: Be sure to specify the types for the other number and date fields.    columns: [
    { field: 'id', title: 'Id', type:'number',width: '80px' },
    { field: 'reportDate', title: 'Report Date', type:'date',width: '100px', format: '{0:yyyy-MM-dd}' },
    { field: 'prog', title: 'Prog', type: 'number', width: '60px' },
    { field: 'state', title: 'Status', width: '130px' },
    { field: 'maxTemps', title: 'Max Temps', type:'number',width: '100px' }
  ]

Comment: Thanks guys for your answers ! I opened a new question for my TypeScript problem.

Comment: I had this issue, too. I had to reference the field's type property in my datasource's schema, like schema: { model: { fields: { SomeNumberField: { field: "SomeNumberField", type: "number" }  } } }. It wasn't enough to specify the field's type in the grid's columns.

Answer (score 2):

It should be "number" in the schema as well. I had "int" and it still didn't work

Comment: This should be the answer, as the marked answer does not work.